# GoogleMock - Leaked mock objects due to cross-referencing mock classes

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, shared-ptr, googletest, googlemock

I have two classes, `Server` and `Client`, each with their own mock class and has a `getClients` and `getServer` method respectively (the actual classes are much bigger, but this is the minimal case).
I want to add a *variable* in the `MockServer` that's returned by the `getClients` method, allowing me to modify this variable in my tests whenever appropriate (note the `clients` variable).

While this works, it will cause the two mock objects to keep each other alive, each keeping a `shared_ptr` reference to the other, causing the test to leak objects.
Please, look at the example provided below.

**Question:** How can I modify the *Mock Classes*, without modifying the interfaces or the `create` functions, to prevent leaked mock objects while preserving the `clients` variable?

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct Client;
struct Server
{
  virtual const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client>>& getClients() = 0;
};
struct Client
{
  virtual std::shared_ptr<Server> getServer() = 0;
};

struct MockServer : virtual Server
{
  MOCK_METHOD0(getClients, const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client>>&());
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client>> clients;  // I want to add this variable...

protected:
  MockServer()
  {
    ON_CALL(*this, getClients()).WillByDefault(testing::ReturnRef(this->clients));  // ...and return it whenever getClients is called.
  }
  ~MockServer()
  {
    clients.clear();  // This doesn't help...
    std::cout << __func__ << " - This is never printed." << std::endl;
  }

public:
  static std::shared_ptr<MockServer> create()
  {
    return std::make_shared<testing::NiceMock<MockServer>>();
  }
};
struct MockClient : virtual Client
{
  MOCK_METHOD0(getServer, std::shared_ptr<Server>());

protected:
  MockClient(std::shared_ptr<Server> server)
  {
    ON_CALL(*this, getServer()).WillByDefault(testing::Return(server));
  }
  ~MockClient()
  {
    std::cout << __func__ << " - This is never printed." << std::endl;
  }

public:
  static std::shared_ptr<MockClient> create(std::shared_ptr<Server> server)
  {
    return std::make_shared<testing::NiceMock<MockClient>>(server);
  }
};

TEST(ExampleOfLeak, testLeakedMockObjects)
{
  auto server = MockServer::create();
  auto client1 = MockClient::create(server);
  auto client2 = MockClient::create(server);
  EXPECT_EQ(server, client1->getServer());
  EXPECT_EQ(server, client2->getServer());
  EXPECT_TRUE(server->getClients().empty());
  server->clients.push_back(client1);  // This causes leaked mock objects!
  server->clients.push_back(client2);  // And this too...
  EXPECT_EQ(client1, server->getClients().front());
  EXPECT_EQ(client2, server->getClients().back());
  // server->clients.clear();  // This prevents mock objects from leaking, but doing this manually everywhere is highly unfeasible. 
}
```

Result:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from ExampleOfLeak
[ RUN      ] ExampleOfLeak.testLeakedMockObjects
[       OK ] ExampleOfLeak.testLeakedMockObjects (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from ExampleOfLeak (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.

foo.cc:43: ERROR: this mock object (used in test ExampleOfLeak.testLeakedMockObjects) should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0x2fc3170.
foo.cc:43: ERROR: this mock object (used in test ExampleOfLeak.testLeakedMockObjects) should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0x2fcbcb0.
foo.cc:22: ERROR: this mock object (used in test ExampleOfLeak.testLeakedMockObjects) should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0x2fd6570.
ERROR: 3 leaked mock objects found at program exit.
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to store and share a mocked object in shared pointers.

Comment: The production code (*Client* and *Server* in this case) cannot be changed. Is there a way to use *weak_ptr*s in the Mock without modifying the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to convert a `weak_ptr` into a `shared_ptr` using the `lock()` method.
This way you can store a `weak_ptr` in you mock class and later convert it.
Though do be careful and make sure the `weak_ptr` hasn't `expired()`.

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct Client;
struct Server
{
  virtual const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client>>& getClients() = 0;
};
struct Client
{
  virtual std::shared_ptr<Server> getServer() = 0;
};

struct MockServer : virtual Server
{
  MOCK_METHOD0(getClients, const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client>>&());
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client>> clients;

protected:
  MockServer()
  {
    ON_CALL(*this, getClients()).WillByDefault(testing::ReturnRef(this->clients));
  }
  ~MockServer()
  {
    clients.clear();
    std::cout << __func__ << " - This is printed." << std::endl;
  }

public:
  static std::shared_ptr<MockServer> create()
  {
    return std::make_shared<testing::NiceMock<MockServer>>();
  }
};

ACTION_P(ReturnWeakToShared, wp)
{
  bool isWeakPtrExpired = wp.expired();
  EXPECT_FALSE(isWeakPtrExpired) << "Dangling pointer.";
  return wp.lock();
}

struct MockClient : virtual Client
{
  MOCK_METHOD0(getServer, std::shared_ptr<Server>());
  std::weak_ptr<Server> server;

protected:
  MockClient(std::shared_ptr<Server> server)
  {
    this->server = server;
    ON_CALL(*this, getServer()).WillByDefault(ReturnWeakToShared(this->server));
  }
  ~MockClient()
  {
    std::cout << __func__ << " - This is printed." << std::endl;
  }

public:
  static std::shared_ptr<MockClient> create(std::shared_ptr<Server> server)
  {
    return std::make_shared<testing::NiceMock<MockClient>>(server);
  }
};

TEST(ExampleOfLeak, testLeakedMockObjects)
{
  auto server = MockServer::create();
  auto client1 = MockClient::create(server);
  auto client2 = MockClient::create(server);
  EXPECT_EQ(server, client1->getServer());
  EXPECT_EQ(server, client2->getServer());
  EXPECT_TRUE(server->getClients().empty());
  server->clients.push_back(client1);
  server->clients.push_back(client2);
  EXPECT_EQ(client1, server->getClients().front());
  EXPECT_EQ(client2, server->getClients().back());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> the two mock objects to keep each other alive

One of them definitely should use a weak reference to the other.

For example

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct Client;
struct Server
{
  virtual const std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Client>>& getClients() = 0;
};
struct Client
{
  virtual std::shared_ptr<Server> getServer() = 0;
};

struct MockServer : virtual Server
{
  MOCK_METHOD0(getClients, const std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Client>>&());
  std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Client>> clients;  // I want to add this variable...

protected:
  MockServer()
  {
    ON_CALL(*this, getClients()).WillByDefault(testing::ReturnRef(this->clients));  // ...and return it whenever getClients is called.
  }
  ~MockServer()
  {
    clients.clear();  // This doesn't help...
    std::cout << __func__ << " - This is never printed." << std::endl;
  }

public:
  static std::shared_ptr<MockServer> create()
  {
    return std::make_shared<testing::NiceMock<MockServer>>();
  }
};
struct MockClient : virtual Client
{
  MOCK_METHOD0(getServer, std::shared_ptr<Server>());

protected:
  MockClient(std::shared_ptr<Server> server)
  {
    ON_CALL(*this, getServer()).WillByDefault(testing::Return(server));
  }
  ~MockClient()
  {
    std::cout << __func__ << " - This is never printed." << std::endl;
  }

public:
  static std::shared_ptr<MockClient> create(std::shared_ptr<Server> server)
  {
    return std::make_shared<testing::NiceMock<MockClient>>(server);
  }
};

TEST(ExampleOfLeak, testLeakedMockObjects)
{
  auto server = MockServer::create();
  auto client1 = MockClient::create(server);
  auto client2 = MockClient::create(server);
  EXPECT_EQ(server, client1->getServer());
  EXPECT_EQ(server, client2->getServer());
  EXPECT_TRUE(server->getClients().empty());
  server->clients.push_back(client1);  // This causes leaked mock objects!
  server->clients.push_back(client2);  // And this too...
  EXPECT_EQ(client1, server->getClients().front().lock());
  EXPECT_EQ(client2, server->getClients().back().lock());
  // server->clients.clear();  // This prevents mock objects from leaking, but doing this manually everywhere is highly unfeasible. 
}
```

```text
Running main() from gmock_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from ExampleOfLeak
[ RUN      ] ExampleOfLeak.testLeakedMockObjects
~MockClient - This is never printed.
~MockClient - This is never printed.
~MockServer - This is never printed.
[       OK ] ExampleOfLeak.testLeakedMockObjects (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from ExampleOfLeak (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make changes to the production code (*Client* and *Server* in this case). Both methods must return *shared_ptr*s.

Comment: Good luck. Your production code has memory leaks due to circular references.

Comment: I must thank you. You comment spurred me to check the implementation more closely. As it turns out, the *Client*, or the production code equivalent that is, actually stores *weak_ptrs* and then converts them to *shared_ptr* using *lock()* while doing checks for *expired()* on the *weak_ptr*. Emulating this, I managed to solve my problem. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: @FredrikEnetorp When posting an answer, don't edit it into an exiting answer. I'm going to skip reviewing on this one. 273K's pretty active and can approve, edit, or reject it however they see fit.

Comment: Right, please add your own answer.